# Xcode Won't Launch

Tags: xcode, terminal, launch

When Xcode won't launch (I double click the launch icon) is there a way to "clean" the environment so that it works again? My Mac restarted in the middle of an update and Xcode won't launch anymore. When I try to open a project in terminal:

```
open myProject.xcodeproj
```

I get the following error:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10699...
```

Comment: i think you need to reinstall the Xcode again

Comment: Hi @Shabirjan yes I agree that could possibly fix it but I am trying to avoid this with a less destructive fix.

Answer (score 0):

I found in this [Apple forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/203144#203144) that this error occurs when an app cannot be launched because it's being updated, which makes sense because my Mac restarted in the middle of an App Store update. So I [manually downloaded](https://support.apple.com/en_US/downloads) the corresponding update for my OS and that fixed my problem.